# JVM does not shutdown

Tags: jvm, shutdown

JVM isn't properly shutting down on end of `public static void main(String [] args)`

When I run `jstack` to see what thread are blocking I get the following output:

```
"Attach Listener" #25 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7d597800 nid=0x8807 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"DestroyJavaVM" #24 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7cb23800 nid=0x1303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-2-thread-1" #22 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c5e6800 nid=0x8603 waiting on condition [0x0000000135843000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000005c02eb440> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c2d2000 nid=0x7403 runnable [0x0000000134551000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #13 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7b973800 nid=0x7003 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #12 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a2b4000 nid=0x6e03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a2a1800 nid=0x6c03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a2a1000 nid=0x6a03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a2aa800 nid=0x6803 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM JFR Buffer Thread" #8 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c939000 nid=0x6603 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"JFR request timer" #6 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7b003800 nid=0x6403 in Object.wait() [0x0000000133501000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c1552480> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x00000005c1552480> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"Signal Dispatcher" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a827800 nid=0x611b runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a81d800 nid=0x540b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7d1de000 nid=0x4f03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000130f2b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c1509e68> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000005c1509e68> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7d1dd000 nid=0x4d03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000130e28000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000005c1509938> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000005c1509938> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7904b000 nid=0x4b03 runnable

"Gang worker#0 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a001000 nid=0x2103 runnable

"Gang worker#1 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a001800 nid=0x2303 runnable

"Gang worker#2 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a014800 nid=0x2503 runnable

"Gang worker#3 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c003000 nid=0x2703 runnable

"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c003800 nid=0x2903 runnable

"Gang worker#5 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c004000 nid=0x2b03 runnable

"Gang worker#6 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c005000 nid=0x2d03 runnable

"Gang worker#7 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a015000 nid=0x2f03 runnable

"G1 Main Concurrent Mark GC Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7b801800 nid=0x4303 runnable

"Gang worker#0 (G1 Parallel Marking Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c80c800 nid=0x4503 runnable

"Gang worker#1 (G1 Parallel Marking Threads)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7c80d800 nid=0x4703 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#0" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d79008800 nid=0x4103 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#1" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a808800 nid=0x3f03 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#2" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a808000 nid=0x3d03 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#3" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a019800 nid=0x3b03 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#4" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a018800 nid=0x3903 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#5" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a018000 nid=0x3703 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#6" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a017000 nid=0x3503 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#7" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a016800 nid=0x3303 runnable

"G1 Concurrent Refinement Thread#8" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a015800 nid=0x3103 runnable

"String Deduplication Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7d1d4000 nid=0x4903 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f9d7a2a2800 nid=0x7203 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 158
```

Anybody an idea what could be a reason for it?

**Using:** Java 8_25, Hibernate 4.3.10 and EhCache

Comment: JVM will not terminate while non-daemon thread `pool-2-thread-1` is running. You should either 1) terminate thread pool explicitly by calling `shutdown()` or 2) create a thread pool with custom ThreadFactory that calls `setDaemon(true)` on newly created threads.

Comment: @apangin I agree but you should give your advice in the form of an Answer not a comment

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will not shut down properly as long as Threads are still running that are non-daemon threads. You need to analyze those.

1. If already debugging or you are able to debug, pause the VM to have a look at all those threads
2. If not debugging, use jstack to "shoot" thread dumps
3. Look for all the Threads that don't have the tag "daemon" in it
4. Those are typically Threads with names "pool-N-thread-N" that come from ThreadPoolExecutor or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor instantiations
5. If under your control, extend those instantiations by passing your own ThreadFactory implementation, giving the Threads proper names, and possibly marking them as a daemon thread (or see #6 as an alternative)
6. if using Spring, make your beans DisposableBean and implement the destroy() method to properly shut down your Executor Service
7. if not using Spring but in a Servlet Context, implement a ServletContextListener to properly shut down your thread pools
8. if not using a Servlet Context add a JVM shutdown hook for clean up

see https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial

see https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-shutdown-hooks